# Can't locate parent view of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two UIButtons that I have programmatically created and added as subviews to my custom UIView. The problem I'm having is that the code that I have that adds them as subviews is called repeatedly, and I'd only like them to be added once.

To do this, I have added this check:

```
if (![calibrateButton isDescendantOfView:self] && ![drainButton isDescendantOfView:self]) {
    [self addSubview:drainButton];
    [self addSubview:calibrateButton];
}
```

The issue is that these buttons keep being added as subviews. So if they're not descendants of my custom view, then who could they be descendants of?

Doing an NSLog of [calibrateButton.superView description] shows that it is indeed my custom view, which leaves me lost.

What is the proper way of ensuring these buttons only get added once, and how can I decipher who their parent view really is?

Comment: try checking with the superview like . calibrateButton.superview == self ?

Comment: Ran that check as well, but still no luck.

Comment: you can try `[self.subviews containsObject:button]`, or you can test with `[button.superview isEqual: self]`, or you can set the tags of the views and check them `button.tag = 1; if (button.tag == 1) { ...`

Comment: When and where are you creating the `calibrateButton` and `drainButton` objects?  Is it possible that you're creating new instances each time before you do this check?

Comment: I'm creating them in my view's "init" method and then I create their frame, position, and UI elements in my "drawRect" method.

Comment: can you please add that part of code in the question ?

Comment: @MarkraM and Thank you so much! Your solutions worked perfectly. At first it didn't work because I was creating new instances of the buttons. I ensured I only created one of each and then used tags to ensure they were only getting added once.